# logging with Mongoid models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have a Rails app with a MongoDB datastore. As a result, the models don't inherit from ActiveRecord::Base. When I try to add logging to the model, like so

```
logger.info "Debug application"
```

rails complains that logger doesn't exist, which makes sense. How do I add the logger functionality back, short of inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base?

Answer (score 1):

Use Rails.logger.info instead of logger.info

from http://jasonseifer.com/2009/08/10/using-the-rails-logger-outside-of-models-and-controllers